# Why can't I bind form data directly to action method parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have action method like that:

```
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase image, int variable)
```

and form element like that:

```
variable 1:<input type="text" name="variable" value="1234" />
```

when I start debugging I am getting following exception:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'variable' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase, Int32)' in 'Stream.Controllers.HomeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parameter name: parameters

what is wrong with this?

Comment: Ok, I solved it out. The problem was when I first request the page. server is invoking Index action. But because of there is not any form posted to server I'm getting this error. Solve is: add new parameterless Index action only returns view. and add [Httppost] attribute to existing one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase image, int? variable)
```

The question mark ( ? ) indicates that variable is a nullable variable and then it can be assigned the null value.

To know more about nullable types, read this on MSDN: [Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: +1, but you should tell this poor person what a nullable int is so he doesn't sit there, scrathing his head, wondering what the question mark is for... I was a .Net developer for years before I ran across them.

Comment: David, I was just doing that while you wrote your comment. :)

Comment: The thing is that the error you're getting is informing just that it's null: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'variable' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'.

Comment: I know what nullable types are? poor person.

Comment: Are you shure, Do you have enough knowledge to answer this question?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<input type="text" id="variable" name="variable" value="1234" />
```

Give an ID and see if you get the same issue...  also, I know you probably know this, but to verify, you did put it within the form being posted, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your `<input>` is in a `<form>` tag, and that the form is the one whose action is being executed.